# slor query for sum of 2 field

Tags: solr, solr4

I have a solr collection.

example:-
collection name: collection1
fields:
test1_count
test2_count
name
address
etc.

I need a solr query like

```
SELECT name,test1_count,test2_count FROM collection1 WHERE test1_count+test2_count >10
```

Is it possible in sole?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it for instance by sorting with a function:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=*:*&sort=if(gt(sum(test1_count,test2_count),10),1,0)%20desc
```

You might want to add additional fields to sort to untie all rows that match the condition.

Comment: Is it possible with fq

Comment: not sure what do you mean. If you mean the sorting, no, it has to be with 'sort'